# The commands for bidi package do not autocomplete?

Tags: texstudio, auto-completion, bidi

I have installed the bidi package on my Texlive 2014 and It works well, however the auto-complete on my TeXstudio (version 2.9.4) do not work for the bidi package's commands. I checked the configure TeXStudio/completion section however I don't see the bidi.cwl over there.

Can you help me in this case.
Regards.

Comment: Can you think that the developers of TeXStudio will provide autocompletion for the hundreds of packages in TeX distributions? I can't.

Comment: See the FAQ: [Why does a command not show up in the completion](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/wiki/Frequently%20Asked%20Questions/#why-does-a-command-not-show-up-in-the-completion)